# search results in the text box with cross symbol

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, rxjs

**update1:**

hey thanks for your reply...but when I type h it shows set of values....and when I select the value it should show in the text box with cross symbol....like in stackoverflow we edit tags

I have a search engine code in angular2.
When I select the search results I need to display the values in the text box With cross button next to it.
Right now I am getting the results.
But when I slect the values, how to display in the text box with cross symbol.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-ya3e4u?file=app/app.component.html

service

```or-tag-here
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  baseUrl: string = 'https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries';
  queryUrl: string = '?search=';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
  }

  searchEntries(term) {
    return this.http
        .get(this.baseUrl + this.queryUrl + term)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

html

```or-tag-here
<input
    (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)">

<ul *ngIf="results">
  <li *ngFor="let result of results | slice:0:9">
    <a href="{{ result.latest }}" target="_blank">
      {{ result.name }}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="close" (click)="delete(currentItem)">X</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code it will help you. [Demo StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-kdjlk3?file=app/app.component.html)

```
<input
    (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)">

<ul *ngIf="results">
  <li *ngFor="let result of results | slice:0:9">
    <a href="{{ result.latest }}" target="_blank">
      {{ result.name }}
    </a>
    <div class="close rigth" (click)="delete(result)">X</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...but when I type h it shows set of values....and when I select the value it should show in the text box with cross symbol....like in stackoverflow we edit tags

Comment: OK, I got it let me investigate how to do it manually because exist a lot of third parties libs

Comment: take a look to this  demo instea input you will use  a div this propertie contenteditable="true" https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-qh2bx3?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: In the output I just see white screen...I dont see any text box....can you help me

Comment: I forgot put a border to the div it is in the top-left

Comment: did you change anything in the search results since in the stackblitz which I provided showed different results for different alphabets but here its showing only one result...its not changing...can you help me and can you give comments so that it will help me in understanding

Comment: sorry I was focusing in the tags I think the keyup event doesn't exist  let me try to fix it. about the tags i is that you are trying to do?

Comment: hey but when I try to do multiple tags its not working fine....you can see the stackoverflow tags as an example

Comment: this is an example or guide of how to do it by your self. If you want you need tu improve check the code its easy

Comment: can you give comments to the code it will help me in understanding much better

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-qh2bx3?file=app%2Fapp.component.html I will comment into the code

Comment: ready I already added comments and a big explanation. I hope it helps you